# How to Fill Empty Properties in a Table Using Map Method in React

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a table using Map Method in React. My table is consisted of `div tag`, due to difficulty of handling `table tag`.
So far, I have almost finished making a table shape, but each row has a different quantity of properties.

[image: Row with different quantity of properties]

I would like to fill the table, even if some rows don't have properties. I thought I could map-base on the longest row, but I'm having trouble with it. Is there any way of filling empty properties in a table?

My code:

```js
  {refinedData && !isEmpty
          ? Object.entries(refinedData).map(([key, values]) => (
              <S.RowBox key={key}>
                <S.CaNameBox>{key}</S.CaNameBox>
                <S.Row>
                  {values.map((item, index) => (
                    <S.ValueBox key={index}>
                      <S.ValueTitleBox>
                        <S.CbNameBox>{item.CB_NAME}</S.CbNameBox>
                        <S.CbCodeBox>{item.CB_CODE}</S.CbCodeBox>
                      </S.ValueTitleBox>
                      <S.Value>{item.value}</S.Value>
                    </S.ValueBox>
                  ))}
                </S.Row>
              </S.RowBox>
            ))
          : 'no data'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you'll need to know the maximum length of any row.
then rather than running a map over values `values.map` you can map over an array of that length.
Like `Array(maxLength).map` then get the item :

```
<S.Row>
  {Array(maxLength).map((_, index) => {
    const item = values[index]
    return (
    <S.ValueBox key={index}>
     <S.ValueTitleBox>
       <S.CbNameBox>{item.CB_NAME}</S.CbNameBox>
       <S.CbCodeBox>{item.CB_CODE}</S.CbCodeBox>
     </S.ValueTitleBox>
     <S.Value>{item.value}</S.Value>
    </S.ValueBox>
   )})}
</S.Row>
```